# Can I run multilevel mediation analyses with only two measurement occasions?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, mediation

I have recently conducted a project which aims to examine whether Treatment (X) affected Anger (Y) via Heart Rate (M).

Treatment was a between-subjects predictor with two levels, treatment 1 vs. treatment 2.

Anger was a continuous outcome variable, which was measured twice (before and after treatment).

Heart rate was a potential mediator, which was also continuous but was only measured once (after treatment).

I planned to run a 2-2-1 multilevel mediation using R but was told that it would not be possible to fit a multilevel model to my data because the within-subjects variable (the level 1 variable) was only measured twice. Instead, I was advised to use change scores for heart rate and run a simple mediation.

Does anyone have any idea of which approach is the best? Is it true that it's wrong to run a multilevel mediation when each participant only produced two responses to the same item?

Comment: Mathematically, what is a 2-2-1 multilevel mediation?

Comment: @Galen Please see pages 253-254 and 258 of this paper: Krull, J. L., & MacKinnon, D. P. (2001). Multilevel modeling of individual and group level mediated effects. Multivariate behavioral research, 36(2). It should explain the 2-2-1 mediation better in a more mathematical way than I can.

Comment: A Bayesian approach would be viable for a 2-2-1 multilevel mediation model if you can put justifiable priors on the parameters.